# Cannot substitute template argument this for type template parameter _Ty

Tags: c++, type-traits

I'm trying to forbid the creation of `const MyClass` type by using static assertion. When a class is declared `const` the `this` keyword is of type `const MyClass*` so i thought this would work

```
class MyClass
{
    static_assert(std::is_const_v<std::remove_pointer_t<this>>, "Can't create const MyClass");
}
```

However I receive the following error `Cannot substitute template argument this for type template parameter _Ty`

Why is my `static_assert` expression not legal?

Comment: Why do you want to disallow a `const Myclass`?

Comment: My goal was to disallow creation of a container of const elements unless the container was declared const. So the original code was something like static_assert(!std::is_const_v<T> || std::is_const_v<std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(this)>>, "Container of const elements must be const");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::remove_pointer_t<>` expects a type, but `this` is a pointer, not a type.

What you would need is `std::is_const_v<std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(this)>>` but that wont work as well because you can't use `this` outside of a non static member function.

As far as I know, there is no way to stop the creation of a const qualified object.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `this` in the context of the `static_assert`. You can put it in a dummy member function, but that won't do what you're trying to prevent, because the type of `this` inside of the member function depends on the `const` qualifier of the member function.

This is also a weird thing to want to do. I don't know why you would ever want to do that.

The easy workaround would be to mark zero functions with `const`, so that the `const` object can't actually call any function. It's not perfect, but you can't do better.